# How to highlight recyclerView item in android

Tags: android

I want know that how to highlight recyclerView item.when the user close the app and open app in next time then change the color recyclerView item whos read the uesr.how it is possible?

Comment: change background color of recycler item

Comment: but how to know that whos item read or not.i want that when user click recyclerView item change color of this item.and save this color for next time.when user second time open app then color is change which click the user in firsttime

Comment: Add a new field in your object to save read status. 
If user clicked the object, update the object's read status to "true". 
In binding view of your recyclerview, check the read status and set the background color according to read status.

Answer (score 1):

Store the Item positions that the user reads and then in the `onBindViewHolder` method of the `RecylerViewAdapter` try this following code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecylerViewAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    //some code....

    if(isRead(position)){
        holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }else
        holder.mView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    }

// readList is the positions that you stored in some array 
// you can use the sqlite database or other logic whatever you prefer to store the positions

private void isRead(int position){

    for(int i = 0;i<readList.length;i++){
        if(readList[i]==position)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: how to store Item positions?

Comment: thanks i sloved my issue.thanku u so much Avinash Joshi

Comment: if my answer has helped you please upvote and accept it